# Access attribute with has_many/belongs to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have my models setup like so

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :gallery_images, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery_images, allow_destroy: true
end

class GalleryImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  belongs_to :gallery_category
end


class GalleryCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gallery_images
end
```

To access my gallery images within my show action (as there are multiple images) I am doing this

```
<% for image in @gallery.gallery_images %>
  <li><%= image_tag(image.photo.url(:gallery_flexslider)) %>
    <p class="flex-caption"></p>  
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Which will display each image, but for each of those images I want to add the corresponding gallery Category within my

```
<p class="flex-caption"></p>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the gallery_category to match the instance of the gallery_image.

I have tried

```
 <% @gallery.gallery_images.each do |image| %>
  <li><%= image_tag(image.photo.url(:gallery_flexslider)) %>
    <p class="flex-caption"><%= image.gallery_category.name %></p>  
  </li>
<% end %>
```

but that doesn't correspond to the correct gallery category that is assigned to the image.

I have also tried:

```
<% @gallery.gallery_images.each do |image| %>
          <li>
            <%= image_tag(image.photo.url(:gallery_flexslider)) %>
              <% image.gallery_categories.each do |c| %>
                <p class="flex-caption"><%= c.name %></p> 
              <% end %> 
            </li>
        <% end %>
```

but that results in an error.

### Edit

So it seems the logic in place is working but my images are being duplicated, in this example there are actually only two images uploaded but I am rendering 4:

[image]

Comment: It would be more Ruby like to use `<% @gallery.gallery_images.each do |image| %>` instead of a `for` loop. Admittedly, the end result is the same.

Comment: If you got a moment then lets debug this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussion, this is how it should work:

```
#app/models/image.rb
Class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :gallery_images
    has_many :galleries, through: :gallery_images
    has_one  :category, through: :gallery_images #-> I think
end

#app/models/gallery.rb
Class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :gallery_images
    has_many :images, through: :gallery_images
end

#app/models/gallery_category.rb
Class GalleryImage < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :gallery
   belongs_to :image
   belongs_to :category
end

#app/models/gallery_category.rb
Class GalleryCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :gallery
   has_many :gallery_images
end
```

Schemas:

```
images
id | image_info | created_at | updated_at 

galleries
id | name | created_at | updated_at

gallery_images
image_id | gallery_id | category_id

gallery_categories
id | gallery_id | name | created_at | updated_at
```

This might not work out of the box

---

If you're looking for something simple, you should also consider just adding a `type` attribute to your `GalleryImages` -

```
gallery_images
id | gallery_id | image_id | type | created_at | updated_at
```

Comment: thanks Rich, I've gone for the simpler approach as initial implementation a bit OTT, still getting duplication error, but thinking that's more the .load() method now